# LINQ search using WildCards character like *, %,?

Tags: c#

Hi I have a collection of name type objects and I want to perform a wild card search on it. For example, if I provide a search Criteria `*ABC` then the returned name should start with `ABC`.  If I provide a search Criteria `ABC*` then returned name should end with `ABC`. If I provide a search Criteria `*ABC*` then returned name should contains `ABC`. If I provide a search Criteria `?ABC` then returned name's second, third and fourth character should be `ABC` respectively and first character can be any character.

Comment: Are we talking LINQ-to-objects here, or LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: @Samuel: Seems like LINQ-to-Objects, as he mentions he has a 'collection of [...] objects'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an extension method you might use

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> MatchesWildcard<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T,string> expression, string pattern)
    {
        var regEx = WildcardToRegex(pattern);

        return sequence.Where(item => Regex.IsMatch(expression(item), regEx));
    }

    public static string WildcardToRegex(string pattern)
    {
        return "^" + Regex.Escape(pattern).
        Replace("\\*", ".*").
        Replace("\\?", ".") + "$";
    }
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
void Main()
{
    var items = new[] { new MyObj { MyProperty = "ABC123" },
                        new MyObj { MyProperty = "123ABC" },
                        new MyObj { MyProperty = "123ABC456" },
    };

    var matches = items.MatchesWildcard(item => item.MyProperty, "???ABC");
}

public class MyObj
{
    public string MyProperty {get;set;}
}
```

(WildcardToRegex taken from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/wildcardtoregex.aspx))

Comment: Your Regex method (which you copied and I typed from the top of my head) is better than mine.

Comment: @ErikHeemskerk - why bother learning RegEx syntax when you've got google? :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need Regex.Escape and Regex.IsMatch().

```
private IEnumerable<Item> FilterList(IEnumerable<Item> list, string query)
{
    string pattern = QueryToRegex(query);

    return list.Where(i => Regex.IsMatch(i.Name, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline));
}

private static string QueryToRegex(string query)
{
    return "^" + Regex.Escape(query).Replace("\\*", ".*").Replace("\\?", ".") + "$";
}
```

Note: [Samuel Jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102250/linq-search-using-wildcards-character-like/3102439#3102439) was better in that his Regex was better, so shamefully fixed it here.

Comment: Ah, but it was all in vain anyway, because Samuel Jack posted a better method to translate the wildcard expression to a regex; mine doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use .Contains , .StartWith , .EndsWith

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://trentacular.com/2010/08/linq-to-entities-wild-card-like-extension-method/) lists an extension method that also is compatible with Entity Framework and LINQ-to-entities.

Example usage:

```
var searchTerm = "*Inc";
var q = db.Customers
        .WhereLike(c => c.CompanyName, searchTerm, '*')
        .ToList();
```

Source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

    public static class LinqExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereLike<TSource>(
            this IQueryable<TSource> source,
            Expression<Func<TSource, string>> valueSelector,
            string value,
            char wildcard)
        {
            return source.Where(BuildLikeExpression(valueSelector, value, wildcard));
        }

        public static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildLikeExpression<TElement>(
            Expression<Func<TElement, string>> valueSelector,
            string value,
            char wildcard)
        {
            if (valueSelector == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector");

            var method = GetLikeMethod(value, wildcard);

            value = value.Trim(wildcard);
            var body = Expression.Call(valueSelector.Body, method, Expression.Constant(value));

            var parameter = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, parameter);
        }

        private static MethodInfo GetLikeMethod(string value, char wildcard)
        {
            var methodName = "Contains";

            var textLength = value.Length;
            value = value.TrimEnd(wildcard);
            if (textLength > value.Length)
            {
                methodName = "StartsWith";
                textLength = value.Length;
            }

            value = value.TrimStart(wildcard);
            if (textLength > value.Length)
            {
                methodName = (methodName == "StartsWith") ? "Contains" : "EndsWith";
                textLength = value.Length;
            }

            var stringType = typeof(string);
            return stringType.GetMethod(methodName, new Type[] { stringType });
        }
    }
```